# C# Dictionary Clear() clears dictionary in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

So I got C# foreach loop which goes like this

```
foreach(Type s in source)
{    
    dic1.Clear();
    dic1.Add(Key1, s.Attr1);
    dic1.Add(Key2, s.Attr2);
    ...
    dic1.Add(KeyN, s.AttrN);
    dic2.Add(ind, dic1);
    ind++;
}
```

It gets the values and sets them correctly, no problem in that.
But when the `dic1.Clear()` is called it clears the `dic1` which was added in the `dic2`
and rewrites the contents of it with the new data being handled resulting N amount of dictionaries with the same data from the last handled data/object. Does the `dic1.Clear()` really affect the one which was added into the `dic2`? If it does should I just copy `dic1` into `dicTemp` and add that one into `dic2`?

Thank you for advance.

Comment: could you provide more context or actual code? its not clear what you are attempting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get your question now.

When you add a reference object to a collection you are storing a reference to the object, not the value.

What you should do is make `dic1` local to the loop body.

```
foreach(Type s in source)
{    
    var dic1 = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
    dic1.Add(Key1, s.Attr1);
    dic1.Add(Key2, s.Attr2);
    ...
    dic1.Add(KeyN, s.AttrN);
    dic2.Add(ind, dic1);
    ind++;
}
```

Comment: *Slaps head* Thats it. Stupid me. Need to try this next time. I will most likely succeed with this. Needs to wait for next week though. I 'll add this one as the answer after I have confirmed it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you operate on only one instace through `dic1` this will lead to:

- All values in `dic2` referring to the same dictionary instance
- that instance being cleared in the beginning of each iteration.

You probably want to change the line `dic1.Clear()` to `dic1 = new Dictionary<X, Y>()`.